# Wrap linearlayouts in relativelayout

Tags: android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-xml, android-relativelayout

I am trying to put two LinearLayouts in a RelativeLayout (rootelement). I can only see one row. Shouldn't the  ÄÄandroid:layout_below** force the second Linearlayout to be positioned below the first LinearLayout?

What is wrong? Is it because LinearLayout in itself is a ViewGroup?

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/addon1_row"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/weapon1_id"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="26dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/weapon1"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="26dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/buy_button"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/addon2_row"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_below="@+id/addon1_row">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/weapon2_id"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="26dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/weapon2"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="26dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/buy_button"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"

        />
</LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You don't really need a RelativeLayout, given your current arrangement. But I'd optimize it all (for performance sake) by using a single RelativeLayout witn no LinearLayouts OR by using a GridView (again, with no extra LinearLayouts).

Comment: @Rotwang, thanks i'll consider that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of you have set the height of both linear layout to `"match_parent"` just set it to `"wrap_content"`

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/addon1_row"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"   <== Here
    android:orientation="horizontal">


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/addon2_row"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"   <== Here
    android:layout_below="@+id/addon1_row"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
```